# Puppet Master doesn't get certificate request from agent

Tags: puppet, certificate, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I have a puppetmaster server and four puppet agent clients. Here I'm attaching my puppet.conf files and hosts in all node. When I call 'puppet cert list' it returns nothing.

But, when called with --all flags it returns the certificate of its own.

I can able to ping puppet, puppetmaster from all agents. 'puppet agent --test' on agents gives the following,
Exiting; no certificate found and waitforcert is disabled

How can I get the certificate requests to master from agents. Can anyone give me a solution to this problem?
[1] puppet.conf
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByrsDKrxH15uaThvQm9VRHBtaTg/view?usp=sharing

[2]hosts
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByrsDKrxH15uVktSYmhDN1NHaGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you run the following command in she shell of your puppet client(s) and post back the result. dig puppet.example.com +short

Comment: It returns nothing

Comment: That is your problem. You are using 'puppet.example.com' as your puppet server, when you can't even resolve puppet.example.com. 'example.com' is an external domain, as soon as your try to access exmaple.com, your DNS client try to resolve it. Why are you using blablabla.example.com??? Why not use IP address of your puppet server in your configuration?

Comment: What version of puppet client are you using? You can either delete the certificate (delete 'ssl' directory and all its sub-directories on puppet client. Then start your puppet client again, it will re-create the certificate. Or you can uninstall, rei-install and change your puppet server address and then run the puppet client.

Comment: Clients and server both are version 3.7.4, I've deleted the ssl directories and edited the puppet.conf files and still the same thing happens in clients.

I mean, it still produce the four lines

`root@mgt2:~# puppet agent --no-daemonize --verbose --waitforcert 2
Info: Creating a new SSL key for mgt2.private.wso2.com
Info: Caching certificate for ca
Info: Caching certificate_request for mgt2.private.wso2.com
Info: Caching certificate for ca
Notice: Did not receive certificate`

Comment: on puppet server you do not see any request to sign the certs?

Comment: nope, no requests

Comment: What is the output on puppetmater when you do this: puppet cert list --all

Comment: root@puppet:~# puppet cert list --all

`+ "puppet.example.com" (SHA256) 76:6E:B8:17:92:50:E6:6C:CD:C5:B4:C2:54:07:11:D4:29:14:00:CD:AA:87:E2:3F:9C:6F:D0:22:A6:F4:F5:13 (alt names: "DNS:puppet", "DNS:puppet.example.com", "DNS:puppetmaster01", "DNS:puppetmaster01.example.com")`

Comment: yeah, no certificate is there to sign. It means you puppet client never found your puppet server.

Comment: Yeah, I can ping from client to server and server to client. But, how can I make sure that client is not finding the server. How to make it happen?

Comment: I think you should wipe the whole thing clean. This 'example.com' domain was a terrible idea. Uninstall everything, make sure your host are not using external domains. install puppet server and then puppet master from scratch. You can test by having master and client on the same machine.

Comment: What is the output of `puppet agent --configprint server`? The exact string that is returned must resolve to an IP on your master node, through which the master service is reachable.

Comment: Please add the content of the `puppet.conf` file to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The first time you run:

```
puppet agent -t
```

on a new puppet client, it creates a certificate request which is sent to the puppet master (as configured in the client's /etc/puppet/puppet.conf).

Then, on the puppet master you should run:

```
puppet cert list
```

Identify the relevant certificate and then sign it:

```
puppet cert sign hostname_of_puppet_client
```

Make sure that the certificate request which is created in the puppet master is identified by a the puppet client's hostname rather than IP cause otherwise it may cause you problems in the future.

Also, make sure that the time on both puppet master and client is sync'ed.

After the certificate is signed properly in the puppet master, you should run again on the client:

```
puppet agent -t
```

Then, the client should download puppet catalog and run the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this I had to restart the puppet master (had to kill the process). I don't know yet why it helped, but perhaps there is some sort of cache in the master for hosts who were signed already (in my case it happened when i wanted to regenerate the certificate for a host)